# How to remove autoindents from generated with dompdf PDF

Tags: php, dompdf

I am using the latest dompdf to generate some agreement.
Here how it looks like finally (on the screen I am using dompdf debug service as you may see in url bar):

[image]

As you see there are some indents aroung the background. I tried to use margin/padding directives in internal css but there no any changes.
Please tell me, may I do something wrong? I use laravel-dompdf package, but I think that the reason of paddings is in setttings or something like that.

Comment: Post the code of 'View' from which you are generating this pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: I needed to use this:

```
@page { margin: 0; }
```